# Export contacts/text messages in a readable format

Tags: contacts, 2.3-gingerbread, sms, backup

I would like to export both my contacts and my text messages. But I would like be able to easily read the file formats that it exports to. I can export the contacts as a VCF yet when I view it there is a lot of other data that I do not need. Is there a way to export the contacts as a file formate that excel can open and read without the other excess data.

Then I would like to export my text messages. I use GO SMS PRO as my text message APP and I can backup the messages yet they backup in a format that I cannot read. Is there a way to export text messages into a format that can be easily readable?

Thanks for the assistance.

(I am running Android 2.3 and using a T-Mobile/HTC G2)

Comment: What excess data is in the VCF?

Comment: It looks like random numbers/letters. I assume that it is data that an email program uses to classify what is what.

Comment: Contacts are stored in an sqlite db.  so you can export them in a csv, by finding the db file and querying it. See [this blog post](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/11/android-how-to-poke-around-the-sqlite3-databases/) `data/data/com.google.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db` is the database file you want.

Comment: If you don't need to do this on the phone, and you're syncing the contacts to your Google account, you can easily export contacts to a .CSV file from the Gmail website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least if using the stock Messaging app [SMS Backup +](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync) can backup your messages in a readable format to your Gmail. And for contacts I'd recommend syncing them to Google Contacts and exporting them from there (as Chahk mentioned in the comments).